# scrapy crawl: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<project_name>'

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, modulenotfounderror

I'm trying to run my scrapy project with the name "ReviewsScraper" through `crawl` command. The spider name is "hotels", when I run:

```
scrapy crawl hotels -a city="تونس" -s filename="tunis_hotels.csv" --loglevel=ERROR
```

I get this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ReviewsScraper'`

I made sure I'm in the project directory...

I came across a solution that mentions something about making my project as a package and adding main.py and **init**.py files, but couldn't understand the approach and how to implement it...so I'm still stuck.

folder structure:

```
.
├── geckodriver.log
├── ReviewsScraper
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── middlewares.py
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── items.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── pipelines.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   └── settings.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── spiders
│       ├── hotels_spider.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __pycache__
│       │   ├── hotels_spider.cpython-38.pyc
│       │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│       │   └── reviews_spider.cpython-38.pyc
│       └── reviews_spider.py
└── scrapy.cfg
```

hotels_spider.py code:

```
from scrapy import Spider, Request
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urljoin
from ..items import Hotel
from re import compile
from os import system
import time

class HotelsSpider(Spider):
    name = "hotels"
    city = ''
    def __init__(self, city):
        self.city = city

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [get("https://www.booking.com/searchresults.ar.html", params={'ss': self.city}).url]
        for url in urls:
            yield Request(url, self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        def getHotelName(hotelDiv):
            try:
                name = hotelDiv.find('h3', {'class':"sr-hotel__title"}).find('span', {'class':"sr-hotel__name"}).get_text()
            except AttributeError:
                name = ''
            return name

        def getHotelLink(hotelDiv):
            ptrn = compile(r'#hotelTmpl')
            try:
                link = hotelDiv.find('h3', {'class':"sr-hotel__title"}).find('a', {'class':["hotel_name_link", "url"]}).attrs['href']
                link = ptrn.sub("#tab-reviews", link)
            except AttributeError:
                link = ''
            return link

        def getHotelStars(hotelDiv):
            try:
                stars = hotelDiv.find('span', {'class':"sr-hotel__title-badges"}).find('i', {'class':["bk-icon-wrapper", "bk-icon-stars", "star_track"]}).attrs['title']
            except AttributeError:
                try:
                    stars = len(hotelDiv.find('span', {'class':"sr-hotel__title-badges"}).find('span', {'class':["bh-quality-bars", "bh-quality-bars--medium"]}).find_all('svg', {'class':["bk-icon", "-iconset-square_rating"]}))
                except AttributeError:
                    stars = ''
            return stars

        def getNbrOfReviews(hotelDiv):
            try:
                nbr = hotelDiv.find('div', {'class':"bui-review-score__content"}).find('div', {'class':"bui-review-score__text"}).get_text()
            except AttributeError:
                nbr = ''
            return nbr

        def getRating(hotelDiv):
            try:
                ratingLabel = hotelDiv.find('div', {'class':"bui-review-score__content"}).find('div', {'class':"bui-review-score__title"}).get_text()
                ratingScore = hotelDiv.find('div', {'class':"bui-review-score__badge"}).get_text()
            except AttributeError:
                ratingLabel = ''
                ratingScore = ''
            return (ratingLabel, ratingScore)

        def getHotelPages(soupObject):
            try:
                lis = soupObject.find('nav', {'class':"bui-pagination__nav"}).find('li', {'class':"bui-pagination__pages"}).find('ul', {'class':"bui-pagination__list"}).find_all('li', {'class':["bui-pagination__item", "sr_pagination_item"]})
            except AttributeError:
                lis = []
            if lis != []:
                links = []
                for li in lis:
                    try:
                        links.append(urljoin("https://www.booking.com/", li.a.attrs['href']))
                    except AttributeError:
                        continue
                return links

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, "html.parser")
        hotelsList = soup.find('div', {'id':"hotellist_inner"}).find_all('div', {'class':["sr_item", "sr_item_new", "sr_item_default", "sr_property_block", "sr_flex_layout", "sr_item_no_dates"]})

        for hotelDiv in hotelsList:
            hotel = Hotel()
            hotel['name'] = getHotelName(hotelDiv) 
            hotel['stars'] = getHotelStars(hotelDiv)
            hotel['nbr_of_reviews'] = getNbrOfReviews(hotelDiv)
            hotel['rating_score'] = getRating(hotelDiv)[1]
            hotel['rating_label'] = getRating(hotelDiv)[0]
            if hotel['name'] != '':
                hotel['reviews_filename'] = "{}.csv".format(hotel['name'])
            else:
                t = time.time()
                hotel['reviews_filename'] = "empty_file_{}.csv".format(t)

            yield hotel
            if getHotelLink(hotelDiv) != '':
                system("scrapy crawl reviews -a hotel_link='{0}' -s filename='{1}' --loglevel=ERROR".format(urljoin("https://www.booking.com/", getHotelLink(hotelDiv)), hotel['reviews_filename']))


        
        yield from response.follow_all(getHotelPages(soup), callback=self.parse)
```

complete traceback (not just once but multiple times):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 112, in execute
    settings = get_project_settings()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/project.py", line 69, in get_project_settings
    settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/settings/__init__.py", line 287, in setmodule
    module = import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ReviewsScraper'
```

any help please ? thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hard to say without seeing any code, the file structure, the full traceback or the directory you are running the command. Did you started your project using `scrapy startproject ReviewsScraper`? Please provide more information.

Comment: @renatodvc ok I'll provide the folder structure and some code in a bit... and yes I did start my project using "scrapy startproject ReviewsScraper"...thanks for interacting in such short notice

Comment: @renatodvc... I just provided some extra info sir.

Comment: There is no reference to `ReviewsScraper` in your code, clearly the error is not there. Since scrapy loads as a package, it's possible that other spiders (like `reviews_spider.py`) is using a erroneous `import` statement. Please check your other files in the project, if that doesn't help the traceback of the execution would help debug this.

Comment: @renatodvc I just checked the files and neither importing is missing nor any errors are highlighted... how can I provide a "traceback" ? 
one more thing... I just noticed that both __init__.py & spiders/__init__.py files are empty , is it normal ?!

Comment: Traceback is the complete error message. You can execute the spider and include in your question the execution logs. About the empty init files, they are completely normal, further read on this [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Comment: @renatodvc  I just provided the traceback...

Comment: Are you running your `crawl` command form inside `ReviewsScraper` or right outside it?

Answer (score 0):

the error was because of this line:

```
system("scrapy crawl reviews -a hotel_link='{0}' -s filename='{1}' --loglevel=ERROR".format(urljoin("https://www.booking.com/", getHotelLink(hotelDiv)), hotel['reviews_filename']))
```

although I don't know the real problem yet, I reformatted my code and got rid of calling the second spider through the first and it is all working well now.

Thanks anyway :)